# Nativescript Simple Delete Function

Tags: javascript, xml, nativescript, typeerror

Okay, so what I'm having trouble is figuring out how to swap the current index with the last index of the pages[] and popping it out.

Here's piece of the code from my fileSystemService.js:

```
fileSystemService.prototype.deletePage = function (notePage) { //Saving pages to the file system
var pages = this.getPages();

//Checking if the page already exists so that it updates it
var index = pages.findIndex(function (element) {
    return element.id === notePage.id;
});
if (index !== -1) { //if the page is found

        notePage.id[index] = pages.id[pages.length-1]
        notePage.title[index] = pages.title[pages.length-1]
        notePage.n[index] = pages.n[pages.length-1]
        notePage.image[index] =pages.image[pages.length-1]
    pages.pop();
}

var json = JSON.stringify(pages); //Converting objs to json and save to the file system
this.file.writeTextSync(json);
```

};

nothing too complex, and here's the link for testing:
https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=0gZPsC&v=5

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
```

Comment: Which line of code is being flagged with the error?

Comment: Ah the error is the notePage.id[index] = pages.id[pages.length-1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alright, so I found the solution to my error.

```
pages[index] = pages[pages.length-1]
pages.pop();
```

since there's no such thing as "id" in the array "pages", therefore, an error was flagged
hope someone found this useful ;v;
solved it at 3 in the morning